# Django: Saving item to database, ForeignKey confusion

Tags: python, django, database, foreign-keys

So I wrote a small Django application serving as some kind of online shopping list. Basically you have two text inputs where you can enter an item you want to buy and an amount in the second CharField. There is a Dropdown menu as well allowing you to choose a category for your item for making the list more clean. The dropdown menu ist being populated from a database. Now everything seems to work fine (adding items to the list as well as querying them), the only problem is that the app seems to save the category seperately making the list with available categories larger and larger (by adding the newly added categories ID to it).
It can be seen here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjUoS.jpg

The text is the categories I added as choices for the user while the numbers are those which get added once you add items to the database.

this is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    count = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

This is my views.py

```
@require_POST
def addItem(request):
    form = ItemForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        category = Category(name=request.POST['category'])
        category.save()
        new_item = Item(text=request.POST['text'], count=request.POST['count'], category=category)
        new_item.save()
```

and this is my forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from .models import Category


class ItemForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=40,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(
                                attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Gib einen neuen Gegenstand ein (z.B. Wasser)', 'aria-label' : 'Item', 'aria-describedby' : 'add-btn'}))
                        
    count = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(
                                attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Gib eine Anzahl ein (z.B. 5)', 'value' : '1', 'aria-label' : 'Count', 'aria-describedby' : 'add-btn'}))
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(),
                               initial=0,
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'aria-label' : 'Kategorie', 'aria-describedby' : 'add-btn'}
                               ))
```

I know my problem is most likely that I save the category (in my views.py file) before saving the new item to the database. However, if I delete that category.save() statement, the debugger tells me

**"save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'category'."**

Everything else if working fine. I really can't get my head around what I am doing wrong. So any help is highly appreciated.

Let me know I if missed to pass you any infos.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Form` is used to save the data of a `Model` the most logical step is to use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform):

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=40,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(
                                attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Gib einen neuen Gegenstand ein (z.B. Wasser)', 'aria-label' : 'Item', 'aria-describedby' : 'add-btn'}))
                        
    count = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(
                                attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Gib eine Anzahl ein (z.B. 5)', 'value' : '1', 'aria-label' : 'Count', 'aria-describedby' : 'add-btn'}))
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(),
                               initial=0,
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'aria-label' : 'Kategorie', 'aria-describedby' : 'add-btn'}
                               ))
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ['complete']
```

Note: If you don't provide the field definitions the `ModelForm` would automatically make them according to the Model.

Now in your view:

```
@require_POST
def addItem(request):
    form = ItemForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        new_item = form.save()
```

#### Note on where you went wrong:

The problem  you had was you were saving the category! Instead of using the category in the form. When you use a form and `is_valid()` returns `True`, `form.cleaned_data` gets populated with the validated and cleaned data. So if you had written `category = form.cleaned_data['category']` you would have gotten the correct instance of `Category` which you could have used directly to save.